# Password String compare [C++]

Tags: c++

Trying to do a password validation method in order to allow a user to use my program.

I was wondering how would someone would implement such a code that allows the program to compare two strings, going down all the letters and numbers to make sure everything matches, and then allows a user to access program controls after successfully entering in a password.

So, for example, if the password is "h3llo" and someone typed in "he" the program will output an error message saying that the password is incorrect.

Here is what I started with:

```
void checkPassword() {
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    string password = "H3110W0r1d";
    int length = password.length();
    int i;
    string input;
    cin >> input;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        if ((input[i].compare(length[i]))) == 1) {
            if ((input[i].compare(length[i])) == 0) {
                cout << "Error! Wrong password!";
            } else {
    cout << "Welcome!";
    }
}
```

I've tried so many different ways, however, I can't seem to get it working. Any help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not `password == input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply just compare one by one.

```
void checkPassword() {
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    string password = "H3110W0r1d";
    int length = password.length();
    int i;
    string input;
    bool ok = true;
    cin >> input;

    if (input.length() != password.length()) {
        ok = false;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
            if (input[i] != password[i]) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ok) {
        cout << "Welcome!";
    } else {
        cout << "Error! Wrong password!";
    }
}
```

Or more simply

```
void checkPassword() {
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    string password = "H3110W0r1d";
    string input;
    cin >> input;

    if (input == password) {
        cout << "Welcome!";
    } else {
        cout << "Error! Wrong password!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to immediately compare the two strings? So like, when a user inputs a character, the program takes that character, matches it with the master password and iterates through until every character matches?

Comment: that's what the first portion of this answer is doing, at line "if (input[i] != password[i])"

Comment: Oh sorry. Dumb me.

Comment: FYI, you should not break the password or key comparing cycle with break due to security reasons (timing attack)